# Monitor health of prometheus deployment within kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, kubernetes, prometheus

The setup is currently this: Kubernetes is deployed on AWS instances within a private hosted zone on AWS (only vpn access to the instances, though there is a NAT gatway), with Prometheus deployed as a stateful set within kubernetes to monitor health.

The question is, how do I set it up so I get an alert of Prometheus itself were actually to go down?  I thought about trying to use a route 53 health check, but it appears that only works with public addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally recommended to have another meta-Prometheus monitoring all your other Prometheus servers. If you're doing federation, you get this for free.

Comment: Ok, I had thought about this, but I was not sure if that was the standard way  accomplishing this.